# Configure PostgreSQL for subdomain access (installing Comment.io)

Tags: domain-name-system, postgresql

I need to provide a comment section for a website I am currently working on. I found commento.io, a commenting platform that can be self-hosted.

They provide a tutorial for self-hosting: https://docs.commento.io/installation/self-hosting/on-your-server/release-binaries.html
Having no real background in server technology, I find this tutorial to be a bit brief regarding the setup.

To be precise, I'm having trouble figuring out how to configure DNS (and Firewall) settings to be able to access the server as seen in the example:

> You need to set up some non-optional configuration before starting Commento. In this example, let's assume our Commento instance will be running on the server and will be available at `commento.example.com`.
>
> Before you launch Commento, you will also need a usable PostgreSQL server. Let's say the server is available at `postgres.example.com` on port `5432` with the credentials `username:password`. Create a database named `commento`.
>
> Set up the environment variables to start the Commento server on `commento.example.com` on port `8080`:
>
> ```
> $ export COMMENTO_ORIGIN=http://commento.example.com:8080
> $ export COMMENTO_PORT=8080
> $ export COMMENTO_POSTGRES=postgres://username:password@postgres.example.com:5432/commento?sslmode=disable
> $ export COMMENTO_CDN_PREFIX=$COMMENTO_ORIGIN
> ```

what I have:

- a Digital Ocean droplet running Ubuntu 18.04
- a PostgreSQL installation with credentials resembling `username:password`
- a database named `commento`
- a UFW firewall currently configured to only allow SSH access
- a domain resembling `example.com` with an A record to my server's IP

What I don't understand:

- How do I make the database accessible via `postgres.example.com`, and do I even need to use DNS for this, or could I simply access it via `postgres://username:password@<MYIP>:5432`?
- How do I configure my server to access my commento instance via `commento.example.com`?
- Do I need to configure the firewall somehow to allow exchange between the two subdomains `commento.example.com` and `postgres.example.com`?

Comment: Progress so far: I have moved my custom domain to Digital Ocean's nameservers, installed an Nginx server, secured it using certbot and added https access to my firewall configuration (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-18-04) Now I have to figure out the rest

Answer (score 0):

To make postgres available from a different host you'll need a listen line in postgresql.conf that lists an ip address that's reacable from the client system. and whatever firewall rules are require to allow this TCP connection on port 5432.

Comment: thank you for the answer! I've moved to using a docker container for my purpose, which makes it a bit easier.